# Error when trying to define a new command

Tags: macros, environments

```
\newcommand{\pas}[2]
{
    \begin{flushleft}
        \(geg.: #1\)
        \(ges.: #2\)
    \end{flushleft}
}
```

Throws:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I have already tried to move the command creation into the document environment, but that just throws the same error.

Here's my whole document:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{extarticle}

% Specify margins here:
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm]{geometry}

% Sets the typeset of the document.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Specify the language of the document here:
\usepackage[german]{babel}

% Adds better mathematical notation handling and symbols.
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

% Adds hyperlinks to the document and makes the table of contents clickable.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue
}

% Adds functionality to the fancyhdr package, in that it makes the number of
% total pages available.
\usepackage{lastpage}

% Adds consistent headers and footers to the document that persist all
% throughout the document.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{Name}
\fancyhead[C]{Zentripetal- und Zentrifugalkraft}
\fancyhead[R]{11-Ph1}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

% Adds margin functionality to the document.
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{question}
{
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}
    \begin{center}
    \small
    ''
}
{
    ''
    \end{center}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \vspace{5mm}
}

\newcommand{\pas}[2]
{
    \begin{flushleft}
        \(geg.: #1\)
        \(ges.: #2\)
    \end{flushleft}
}

% Defines new font face for the document.
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Defines the specifications of the naming of the document
\title{Zentripetal- und Zentrifugalkraft}
\author{Name\\Kurs 11-Ph1}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{Aufgabe}

\begin{question}
    Ein Körper \(m = 0,4kg\) wird an einer \(0,8m\) langen Schnur \(80-mal\) in
    der Minute auf einem Kreis, der in einer waagerechten Ebene liegt,
    herumgeschleudert. Berechnen Sie die Zentripetalkraft und die
    Umdrehungszahl, bei der die Schnur reißt, wenn ihre Zugfestigkeit mit
    \(500N\) angegeben ist.
\end{question}

\pas{m = 4kg}{\omega}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. If I put this code into a naïve minimal document, it compiles without any issues.

Comment: The supplied document runs without error.

Comment: show the full error from the log, are you sure it is that line causing the problem?